# How to use grep to find values in two files that don't intersect?

Tags: grep

I have 2 files.

File_A:

```
A 
B 
C
```

File_B:

```
C 
D 
E
```

How can I use grep to find data points in File B that don't match with File A? Ideally, I want File C (output) to contain: `D E`

I tried:

```
grep -v File_A File_B > File_C
```

It didn't work because it returned the whole `File_B`.

(I know that to find the points that intersect between the two files, I can do `grep File_A File_B > File_C`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
root@zim:~/testing# cat file_a
A
B
C
root@zim:~/testing# cat file_b
C
D
E
root@zim:~/testing# grep -v -f file_a file_b
D
E
```

So, you say `-v` for everything that doesn't match, and `-f file_a` for get the patterns from file_a.

If you want to write it to a file:

```
root@zim:~/testing# grep -v -f file_a file_b > file_c
root@zim:~/testing# cat file_c
D
E
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I tried it, it gave me a blank File_C and my terminal stopped working.

Comment: It works with the test data you provided. Can you give us subset of the actual data you are working with?

Comment: I just tried it on a different computer, and it works. I think my computer can't handle the amount of data being processed. Thanks a bunch!